# JFace Action Dropdown Looks Like 2 GUI Elements: A dropdown and a button

Tags: eclipse, dropdown, action, jface

CentOS 7
GNOME 3
Eclipse 4.6.1

org.eclipse.jface.action

I impleented a JFace Action as a dropdown menu:

```
   public class ToolRelevantDropDownAction extends Action
            implements IWorkbenchAction, IMenuCreator {

        private static final String ID = "com.acme.action";

        public ToolRelevantDropDownAction() {
            super("Tool Actions", Action.AS_DROP_DOWN_MENU);
            setId(ID);
            setToolTipText("Actions");
            setMenuCreator(this);
        }

        ...
     }// end class
```

The result is a dropdown that looks like 2 GUI elements, a dropdown and a button.

Is it possible to remove the gap in between "the two" and make it look like 1 button, 1 GUI element?

[image: dropdown that looks like a dropdown AND a button]

Comment: JFace/SWT generally doesn't provide any way to change the way controls look.

Comment: Does it look different from that control when it's used outside of Eclipse?

Comment: The screen shot is from a piece of an application that runs outside of Eclipse